# Maven and JPA (Dali) project in Ecplise - Reverse Engineer

Tags: database, eclipse, jpa, reverse-engineering, dali

I want to create a JPA project in Eclipse but at the same time have it as a Maven project with the tipical maven source directory structure.

Can this somehow be done?

I just want to use the Dali feature to reverse engineer my database structure to JPA beans, but if I use a Maven only project I get a error that the project isn't a JPA project.

Is there some easier way to reverse engineer my beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible when you use the [m2e Eclipse plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). The documentation is a bit scarce but it really works just like you know it from the Maven command line. I suggest to create projects with the "New Maven Project" wizard to get you started.

You should also be able to activate the JPA nature for the same project (one project can have any number of different "natures").

If it doesn't work, open a new question giving specific information like error messages.

PS: You will want m2e 1.200 and Eclipse 3.7.2.

Comment: You should be able to add the JPA Facet to the project by right-click on project->Configure->Convert to JPA Project.  Eclipse 3.7.2 (Dali JPA Tools 3.0.2) and higher are recommended for Maven integration.  The m2e Eclipse plug-in isn't explicitly required, but may help with general maven integration.